# Footer on foot of page with different width content div

Tags: html, css

I have header of 100% width and contant of 980px and footer of 100% width. But the footer is not sitcking to the bottom of the page. its depends on contact div. Please see my below code and let me know if there is any problem in coding.

I search all the post but nothing work for me. If you see google.com footer, its always on the foot what ever the screen resolution.

```
     * {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }

    body, html {
            position: relative;
            background-color: #fff;


height:100%;
    }

    .contents {
        position: relative;
        width: 980px;
              margin: 0 auto;
        background-color: red;
        clear:both;
    }

    /* Header of the page */
    .header {
        height:100px;
        width:100%;
        background-color:#000099;
    }

    /* footer of the page */ 
    .footer {
       clear:both;
       background:#6cf;
       position:absolute;
       bottom:0;
       width:100%;
       margin-top:5px;
       height : 100px;
    }

    <body>
    <div class="header">
    here is the header
    </div>

    <div class="contents">
    <p>Contents</p>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
    <p>Footer</p>
    </div>

    </body>
```

Comment: I think we need to go for JS in this case ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from scratch. This is my favourite sticky footer recipe. Adapted from [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/)

The footer is independent of the wrappers contents. It's effectively pushed out of the viewport and then pulled up by the negative margin. It will scale to any height regardless of how much content you put into it.

[Endless content fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/eVEBG/7/show/)

[Basic idea fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eVEBG/)

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* same height as footer */
    margin-bottom: -120px;
}
#wrapper:after {
    content:"";
    display: block;
}
#header {
    height: 200px;
    background: #FF0;
}
#footer, #wrapper:after {
    /* same height as wrapper negative margin */
    height: 120px;
}
#footer {
    background: #F00;
}
```

Comment: Yes I saw this too, But in this the width of the header is same as wrapper. Can you set 100% of the window to header and 980px for content ?? My case is I want 100% width to header and footer and content 980px

Comment: Of course :) [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/eVEBG/3/). The wrapper and header are 100% and the content is smaller and centered. The height of the content div is not needed, that's just for example.

Comment: See the problem in this code. I update your fiddle. If you increase the contant its gonig above footer http://jsfiddle.net/eVEBG/4/

Comment: offfffffffffff......... ITS PERFECT........ I struggle alot for this... Thank You...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
}
.header {
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#000099;
}
.contents {
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 980px;
    /* equal to footer height */
    margin-bottom: -100px;
}
.contents:after {
    content:"";
    display: block;
}
.site-footer {
    /* .push must be the same height as footer */
    height: 100px;
    width:100%;
}
.site-footer {
    background:#6cf;
}
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/EyGNp/2/

Comment: Sorry to say I already have margin and padding to 0px. I update the question. But its the same. If you see the jfiddle u provided if u add contant then fotter is moving. please check the updates of ur jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wL3SC/1/

Comment: Updated the answer :) + demo

Comment: If u reduce the content it is mving above. Please check the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wL3SC/3/

Comment: Trying to fix it... one sec

Comment: Blv me I did this yesterday but I quit because scroolbar coming even for not having any content. If you see you fiddle there is a scrool bar.

Answer (score 0):

If you want you footer to always be at the bottom of the page, but not a sticky-footer that displays when the content is longer than the viewport, you can use calc() to calculate the min-height of the content div.

```
.contents {
  position: relative;
  width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
  clear:both;
  min-height: calc(100% - 205px);
}
```

What this does is set the min-height of the contents div to 100% of it's container, less the height of the header and footer.  It will therefore, force the contents div to grow if there is less content than the viewport forcing the footer to the bottom of the screen.

Here's the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/SFYP6/)**.

Comment: position fixed will fixed the footer but not on the foot of the page. It is always visible.

Comment: Position fixed will create a sticky footer, yes.  I thought that's what you wanted.

Comment: @NjSubedi yes, thank you.  I'm not sure if OP wants a sticky footer or not.